# Deleting the WINDRIVER partition

Tags: partitioning

After I took my laptop (with only Linux installed) to a repair center, I noticed the new 2 GB ntfs WINDRIVER partition, and I am almost sure it didn't exist before. In any case, it seems like a Windows recovery partition from the little info that I found online, and it could be a leftover from the service. However, I would like to double check — is it really safe to delete this partition? Can it result in any data loss if I do it from the existing system?

Comment: That is for you to decide. Mind that your question is not about Linux and not about Ubuntu. If you want more info on a windows partition you should ask this someone that uses windows ;)

Comment: Are you sure it did not exist prior to you getting the laptop repaired. It sounds rather rude from a repair service provider to install something on your laptop. Generally speaking Ubuntu or any GNU/linux system I know of for that matter does not need an ntfs partition to function.

Comment: I just thought it could really serve other purposes as well. I am pretty sure coz this laptop came with a blank hard drive and has never had Windows, but they said they had to test the sound card with Windows. Yet in doubt.

Comment: Why not ask the service centre if they added it? Alternatively use GParted to make a copy of the partition on another device and then delete it. If you hit problems just restore it. Make sure you have something that can boot a live environment with GParted included